# problem with kinect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
what is the solution of this error
[image: image description]

it appears when i do these commands

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
```

&

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

also pointcloud2 doesn't appear
I'm using fuerte on Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55216/problem-with-kinect/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-14**:
Try using openni.launch that comes with openni_launch package.

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-14**:
I have actually tried this but it does not solve this problem

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-14**:
The error says that nodelet already exist with same name. Try doing rosnode list and see whether these nodes exist without even launching kenect.launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same problem, here is how you fix it.

```
 1- open up a new terminal and type `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`
 2- after it launches,  kill it by typing `ctrl^c`
 3- in this terminal, type `killall XnSensorServer` (it might tell you `no process is found`)
 4-in another terminal. launch the`roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch`
 5- If it still does not work, go back to step 1 and repeat. Sometimes it takes a few times.
```

Hope this fixes your problem. post back with the results.

regards.

Khalid

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-14**:
Thanks,I'm going to try it and tell you the results :)